# how to take information from html input and pass into nodeJS variable

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have one question.
I have form in index.html page(see below).

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="customer name"/>   
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and have also server.js page with code as you see in below

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/api/customers", (req, res) => {
var name = req.body.name;
const customers = [
{ id: 1, firstName:name}
];
res.json(customers);
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server  ${port}`));
```

Now my question is: 
When I am writing something in my input I want to take that text and pass it into my nodeJS.
For example if I write "Test" and press "Submit" button it should show "[{"id":1,"firstName":"Test"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `fetch` to make a request and then get it's response,

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    name : e.target.value
  })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { name : this.state.name };
    fetch('/api/customers', {
      method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({ customers : result}, () => {
        console.log('Success:', result);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

and you can use the `handleInputChange` and `handleSubmit` in the form,

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} placeholder="customer name"/>   
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  <div id="result">{this.state.customers && this.state.customers.map(cust => {
    return (
      <span key={cust.id}>{cust.name}</span>
    )
  })}</div>
</form>
```

Comment: In this way it is worked, but I can't get that json information to show in my frontend

Comment: i have edited my answer, now you can use that info in the frontend

Comment: Can you write same solution for ReactJS?... I write something like this
onstructor(){
super();
    this.state ={
      customers:[]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/api/customers')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(customers => this.setState({customers},() => console.log('customers fetched..', customers)));
  }

Comment: you can move the api call to the `handleSubmit` method, I have edited the answer check it now.